# Dynamically set form placeholder text with helpers in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, dynamic, helper, placeholder

I am building an app with different post "templates".  Each form for a Post is identical except for the placeholder text.  I am trying to figure out how to set the placeholder text dynamically.  I've been trying to name all of the template Helpers the same name save for a @template.id at the end.  I can't seem to get the dynamic function to work.

```
 def title_template_1
      'Placeholder for Template 1 Title'
   end

  def title_template_2
  'Placeholder for Template 2 Title'
  end


 <%=    f.text_field :title, 
:placeholder => title_template_1 %> 

 <%=    f.text_field :title, 
:placeholder => title_template_'#{@template.id}' %>#this doesn't work, but I'm showing it to show the functionality I'm trying to achieve.
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead of `title_template_'#{@template.id}'`

```
:placeholder => send("title_template_#{@template.id}")
```

Comment: Ah!  Thank you! I couldn't not figure that out....and now I see why. I learned something new.